# Python selenium - changing a URL during the test, request is not finished and the script hangs

Tags: python, selenium

I have a testing scenarios which run on certain url, when i change the url the browser hangs on the changed url, no 'Finished Request' in the log.
any idea why the browser hangs? I can see that the browser is presenting the new url - all elements are presented, when I manually refresh the browser the script continues.

```
class ArmingScenarios(unittest.TestCase):
    LogFile.logfilename

    def testing_arming_scenarios(self):
        driver.get(config.get('WeRURL', 'wer_url'))
        Login.login(driver)
        Arming.arming(self,'dashboardScreenStatusTxt',config.get('Arming','arming_button'),config.get('Arming','disarm_button'))
        driver.get(config.get('WeRURL', 'history_url'))
        Testing.validate_history(self,driver)
        print('Pass')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not running on current versions of both `Chrome` and `chromedriver`, please update to **Chrome build 65** and **chromedriver 2.37** [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). To update your Chrome, go to `help > About google chrome` and it should update automatically. If you cannot update to current builds, try using this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ChromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('your/path/to/chromedriver.exe', 
chrome_options=ChromeOptions)
```

Also, refer to [Python - selenium webdriver stuck at .get() in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666620/python-selenium-webdriver-stuck-at-get-in-a-loop/48692986#48692986), for more help about `.get()` hang issues with selenium.

Comment: Thanks! that did the job!

Comment: Glad I could help :)