# Getting current page url with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to open a page. I'm trying to get the current opened page url but I can't seem to get it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import getpass

vid = 'https://openload.co/f/KgNvMOs9fws/C__Program_Files_Python36_placeholder.mp4'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('load-extension=C:/Users/'+getpass.getuser()+'/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/leallakffbiflfgpmamdgcojddnbfdgo/1.1.8_0')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
print('Start')
driver.get(vid)
print('Middle')
urlpage = driver.current_url
print(urlpage)
print('End')
```

I have a chrome extension that modifies the url of the video. I'm trying to grab that modified page url, but there is no point in adding a time delay since I can't grab the url of the video page in the first place for some reason. And `driver.current_url` is not working.

Comment: what is the output of your script above?  how is it "not working"?

Comment: There is no output, it just hangs indefinitely until end the program.

Comment: and has it navigated to the target web page?

Comment: Yeah, it opens the url I put just fine, but hangs forever on `driver.get(vid)`

Comment: well, then there is no problem with the driver.current_url, it never gets that far.  the problem is with the path you have in the variable "vid".  can you open that in the same browser manually?

Comment: It does, seems that the issue is selenium grabbing the url after the page has changed, as after I removed the loaded extension it grabbed the page url. However I've read that current_url is dynamic and will just grab the current page regardless so I'm lost why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having issues with `.get()`, then you must be on a bad combination of **chromedriver** and **Chrome browser**.

I would recommend updating to *chromedriver 2.36* or **Above** from [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

And also make sure you have updated to the current *Chrome Build 65* by opening this URL:

> chrome://settings/help

If you cannot update to current, please try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ChromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('your/path/to/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=ChromeOptions)
```

For my original answer on this issue, please refer to **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666620/python-selenium-webdriver-stuck-at-get-in-a-loop/48692986#48692986)**

Comment: I've done this and same result, added a comment with the results.

Comment: So, it's getting passed the `.get()` now?

Comment: No, its not returning the pages url after it changes. If I disable the extension that changes the pages url it works, but when the extension is enabled it returns to not working. Which would be ok except I am under the impression that it should return the url of the page at the current instance.

Comment: by *"return the url"*, you mean it should progress passed the `.get()`? Or are you actually getting to the `current_url`? If you are still hanging on `.get()`, is the page loading or does it seem to load forever? Check circle in top left.