# Try/except for broken urls

Tags: python-3.x, get, python-requests

I'm trying to tell my script to get contents from a url or otherwise log it as an error.

I saw an example in [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module) but it does not seem to work for the url in the code below.

The url is broken so I would expect the script to do the except block and log the error. It just gets stuck with no results or error.

```
import requests
import sys

url = 'https://m.sportsinteraction.com/fr/football/international/coupe-du-monde-feminine-pari/fifawomen-wc-219-reach-the-semi-finals-scotland-05-21-2019-322-1609228/'
try:
    r = requests.get(url)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print (e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Below is a snip of the error I get:

[image]

Comment: The URL provided doesn't seem broken

Comment: @Fozoro Strange! I've edited to show a snip of the error I got

Comment: hmmm, strange are you talking about [this url](https://m.sportsinteraction.com/fr/football/international/coupe-du-monde-feminine-pari/fifawomen-wc-219-reach-the-semi-finals-scotland-05-21-2019-322-1609228/)? when I visit it I don't get this screen

Comment: @Fozoro, yes that same url! Maybe the url is blocked for certain locations? What exception can I use to capture such errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is quite an interesting one because of the following:

1. The script is syntactically correct
2. The url opens in certain locations

Since I'm using an older Chrome, I initially tried the solution of [Python - selenium webdriver stuck at .get() in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666620/python-selenium-webdriver-stuck-at-get-in-a-loop) but the solution persisted.

The next solution I then tried was to put a timeout on the get() statement, in other words:

```
import requests
import sys

url = 'https://m.sportsinteraction.com/fr/football/international/coupe-du-monde-feminine-pari/fifawomen-wc-219-reach-the-semi-finals-scotland-05-21-2019-322-1609228/'
try:
  r = requests.get(url, timeout = 3)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
  print (e)
  sys.exit(1)
```

This solution worked by stopping the request after the stipulated time, before going to the except block.